# Why doesn't filter_input accept PHP superglobals instead of array value?

Tags: php

Why isn't **`filter_input()`** fed directly with the elements of `$_POST` AND `$_GET` arrays? Instead, it receives `INPUT_GET` or `INPUT_POST` and the element index as first and second arguments, plus the rule as third argument.. .

For example, why not be able to simply write:

```
filter_input($_POST['element'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Instead of:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'element', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is a matter of language design.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an implementation. If you only need a way to filter a variable then you'll find **[`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)** a better alternative. Since you only need to pass the variable and the filter.

```
filter_var($_POST['element'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```